# What's wrong with an iterative (with counter) hashed salted KDF?

Tags: hash, passwords, collision-resistance, key-derivation

It seems like the brain-dead simplest KDF would have a key-stretching structure that is not substantially different from $\text{hash}(S | P | S | P |\dots|S|P)$, where $S$ is a salt and $P$ is a password. Other protocols generally require lots of hashes-of-hashes-of-hashes; this one builds up one big string to hash. This naive version has some obvious problems with timing (longer passwords require longer to verify), but it also might be easier to parallelize because the structure is perfectly repetitive, and it might "fall into a fixed point" of the hash function's compression-function, whereby further repetitions do not increase security.

The obvious thing to do, then, involves pre-hashing the password and incorporating a counter. Just to make this question 100% unambiguous, one implementation of this idea in Node.js would be:

```
function createKDF(work_factor, output_length, hash_algorithm) {
    var crypto = require('crypto'), hash_length, output_blocks;
    function hash(string) {
        var context = crypto.createHash(hash_algorithm);
        context.update(string, 'utf8');
        return context.digest();
    }
    hash_length = hash("").length;
    // needed to support arbitrary output lengths
    output_blocks = Math.ceil(output_length / hash_length);
    function output_transform(bin_data) {
        var buff = new Buffer(hash_length * output_blocks), i, bstring;
        bstring = bin_data.toString('hex');
        for (i = 0; i < output_blocks; i += 1) {
            hash(i + ':' + bstring).copy(buff, i * hash_length);
        }
        return buff.slice(0, output_length).toString('hex');
    }
    return {
        createSalt: function () {
            return crypto.randomBytes(hash_length - 4).toString('hex');
        },
        kdf: function (pass, salt) {
            var hpass = hash('nodejs-passwords-0:' + work_factor + ':' + output_length + ':' + pass),
                salt_buff = new Buffer(salt, 'hex'),
                buff = new Buffer(2 * hash_length),
                hash_state = crypto.createHash(hash_algorithm),
                round;
            assert(salt_buff.length + 4 == hash_length);
            // buffer: [32-bit counter][(N - 32)-bit fixed salt][N-bit hpass]:
            salt.copy(buff, 4);
            hpass.copy(buff, hash_length);
            for (round = 0; round < work_factor; round += 1) {
                buff.writeUInt32LE(round, 0);
                hash_state.update(buff);
            }
            return output_transform(hash_state.digest());
        }
    };
}
```

The reason I ask is that this approach seems simple enough that, if it is secure, the common advice of "don't roll your own crypto" is somewhat wrong: there are a variety of implementations of $$\text{key} = h_1(0|S|h_2(P)|1|S|h_2(P)|2|S|h_2(P)\dots)$$which you can easily program to create a password-storage system which suits your particular application, if something like PBKDF2 or bcrypt or scrypt is not available in your programming environment.

(Of course Node.js **has** PBKDF2, so the above implementation is more to clarify the question of "what's wrong with this general approach?" rather than it is to be useful to a JS programmer.)

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: You put less of a burden an any attacker trying to brute-force this.**

And please note: Implementing PBKDF2 shouldn't be much harder than implementing your approach.

Now let's head over to the explanation why "your" scheme is really bad for password-hashing.

The scheme you propose is that each try cost you exactly *two* hash-function evaluations. One for the first hashing of the password and another for the evaluation of the outer hash.

From a theoretical point of view this is bad because you don't require a certain amount calls to a given function that has a "lower bound" on speed. Memory operations XOR and similar don't count usually. So you have only two evaluations and can only tweak something that doesn't really make a difference.

The last point is that "your" scheme ignores the way how hash-functions work. Hash-functions tend to get faster (measured in bytes / cycle) the more data is fed into the function. So your scheme requires one large invocation with small workload per byte, hence you'd have to feed in *much* more data (10-1000x) to reach the same workload. PBKDF2 needs less because hash-functions are inefficient for small amounts of data.

To concern your question what would be the disadvantages against PBKDF2 and co.
**PBKDF2** is standardized ("your" scheme isn't) and widely accepted for usage (although generally considered the worst option).
**bcrypt** is generally considered a good choice as it puts a burden on the minimal memory ("you" don't) and is hard to compute on GPUs ("your" scheme seems very GPU-friendly, like PBKDF2)
**scrypt** is generally considered a very good choice as it puts even more of a burden on the memory side and protects quite good against FPGAs and ASICs ("your" scheme doesn't).

Comment: I agree that bcrypt and scrypt are better KDFs than PBKDF2, but my question is more precisely whether there is a security reason to prefer PBKDF2 to the "dirt-simple" approach. I do think that you're strangely accusing me of your own sin ("your scheme ignores the way how hash-functions work"), since the *reason* hash functions "get faster" is because of pre- and post-processing that isn't much related to their security properties. (In SHA256's case, for example, one hash of a 512-bit input is two compressions: the input and the fixed block 0x800000...00 inserted by the padding preprocessor.)

Comment: @ChrisDrost First, If you think "I'm accusing you" in any offensive sense, then I have to excuse, my text wasn't meant to be offensive. The security property that is interesting for us here (in password-hashing) isn't collision resistance but rather preimage and 2nd preimage resistance and of course speed. If a calculation is slower with lesser parameters and can't be optimized further, it's a good construction. Pre- and postprocessing can be used to the derivators advantage using PBKDF2 but not using "your" scheme (sorry honestly don't know any better short name).

Comment: Well then you should *love* the above construction. The above (running in interpreted JS!) with work_factor 10 million takes as long as Node.JS's PBKDF2 native code (C or C++) with work factor 200,000 and HMAC-SHA256. Each round of the latter may be 4 or 5 compression function calls; so in the same time you get over a factor-of-ten more "work" done. That's why I'm really interested in things like preimages, parallelization, and stuff -- and why I feel like your answer doesn't really get to the heart of the question.

Comment: @ChrisDrost Well that you need more iterations for the same workload is actually bad for password-hashing as it's the aim of password-hashing to slow people down. By using such schemes you want to slow people down so they can't try as much as passwords in the same time as it's possible now. In fact parallelization is also something you want to avoid in most cases because attackers usually have *more* cores than you.

Comment: Amendment to my earlier comment: there is also a hidden factor of 2 from the fact that PBKDF2 redoes the whole chain of computations twice to get a 512-bit key; that surprised me but it sort of makes sense. I must confess that I can't fathom the meaning of "more iterations for the same workload" -- compression function calls *are* the workload, so  this phrase should be "more work for the same time", but obviously that's not BAD but GOOD for password hashing, since ASICs can be designed to cut through overhead.

Comment: @ChrisDrost, "your" scheme suffers from the same problem and PBKDF2 usually is only used to derive "small" keys (256-bit for SHA-256) meaning one "full iteration chain". And usually the keying material is of constant size and hence this isn't an issue as iteration count is usually derived empirically.

Comment: @ChrisDrost "more iterations" means higher security parameters and I do see that the calls to the compression function are your workload (as it's the case for PBKDF2). And maybe this will help you understand: "Iterating the same function many times just *feels* more natural than using the underlying function many times and doesn't need *any* assumptions on the underlying construction".

Comment: 'more iterations means higher security parameters' -- what the heck is a "security parameter" here? I mean if you mean literal numbers, you should prefer 10 million to 200 thousand. If you're counting compressions then you should prefer 10 million to 1.6 million. Either way, this doesn't sound fruitful. // 'Iterating... doesn't need any assumptions on the underlying construction' --See, now **THAT** is the sort of interesting comment I'm looking for. **What is the assumption that is needed for the above scheme that is not needed for PBKDF2?** And what security is at stake?

Comment: @ChrisDrost, usually a "security parameter" is a (literal) number. I'd prefer to be save with 100k instead of being urged to use 10m for the same security level. The above scheme relies solely on the compression function. First, people like the "prove" security based on "complete" functions and not on "helper" functions. Second, the above scheme assumes that the compression function can't be sped up for repeatedly the same input, PBKDF2 doesn't assume this (Although I can't think of an exploit right now...)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I'm really learning anything from this thread. I mean, I've learned that you in particular happen to have a thing for smaller numbers even when the numbers measure totally different things. You don't even seem to care that what you're minimizing is "work the attacker has to do", and when I've asked you in bold letters if you can tell me anything else, you seemed to completely ignore the request. I'm sure you're great at other aspects of crypto, but I really don't feel enlightened about my question -- I feel like I've just received vague, inappropriate platitudes.

Comment: @ChrisDrost, I indeed like small numbers :) And I think the problem we two have is that, **there's no *hard* argument against the above scheme**, I think it won't fail in the wild, so I mainly provided you with reasons why PBKDF2 would be chosen over the above scheme. This includes, the following reasons (from my comments): PBKDF2 can assume $H$ to have $o(1)$ run-time, the above scheme needs the run-time $O(f(l)), f'(l)>0 \forall l \in R^+$, small numbers for same workload are preferrable, iterating on the internals just *feels* wrong, so people iterate on whole functions.